# NPM install PhantomJS without Downloading

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, phantomjs, karma-runner

Ok, I can't provide many details, since the information belongs to the company I am working and I can't upload all our server-files and so on. We use maven to install npm and node. In addition we use shrinkwrap, where all the tar files are at. So when I run a maven install locally everything works fine.

However when the Backend-Team tries to deploy everything on the server PhantomJS is causing problems. Even though we have a phantomJs inside the shrinkwrap-folder it gets ignored and the server downloads PhantomJS from https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads

Sometimes the download fails, sometimes it works. When it works then the next problem occurs:

```
[INFO] [INFO] [16:40:21] Starting Karma testrunner
[INFO] [INFO] PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
[INFO] [INFO]   TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object 
INFO] [INFO]   TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.427 secs / 0 secs)
```

It just makes no sense. When running locally all Tests succeed, no errors.

So my question would be, how can I stop nodejs from downloading PhantomJS and install it with a local file i upload to the server?

Comment: npm packages, including phantom, are platform dependent. Is the platform you're developing on the same you're deploying to?

Comment: Well we have a Linux-Server, on which the applicaiton-server gets deployed and I am developing on Windows. But when he downloads Phantom, when building on the Linux-Server, he downloads the Linux-Version: [INFO] > node install.js
[INFO] 
[INFO] PhantomJS not found on PATH
[INFO] Downloading http://cnpmjs.org/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

Comment: Have you tried logging on your server, download PhantomJS from http://cnpmjs.org/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 extract it and add it to the PATH ? (that way, next `npm install`, it will install / update your `node_modules` but wont download PhantomJS binary) - this will work unless you're working on containers (that may get cleaned up)